# Regex replace phone numbers with XXXXXXXXXX

Tags: regex, awk, sed, replace

I have a text file consisting of few phone numbers and other important data. I would like to replace all the phone numbers to a predefined text, lets say XXXXXXXXXX.

How to do it using sed/awk? The regex

```
^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$
```

did not work for me.

Input:

```
Add me 7598128789
Pls add mi 9761500634
Add 8870504046
spam post
magar maddam is not required
all hero hain
All follows
```

Output:

```
Add me XXXXXXXXXX
Pls add mi XXXXXXXXXX
Add XXXXXXXXXX
spam post
magar maddam is not required
all hero hain
All follows
```

Comment: if you read `man` pages, you'll find that BRE/ERE do not support `\d` or non-greedy or unnamed captured groups, etc

Comment: yes, always 10 digits.

Comment: @Sundeep, \d would be a required parameter, right? 
The sed expression doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: your sample and comments and regex tried all create for plenty of confusion... why do you need `[-. (]` if phone numbers are all 10-digits only? `\d` is shortcut for `[0-9]` in some regex flavors but won't work in BRE/ERE...

Answer (score 1):

you can do like in perl.

```
cat a |perl -npe 's/\d{10}/XXXXXXXXXX/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
gawk '{gsub(/[0-9]{10}/,"XXXXXXXXXX");print}'   Input_file
```

simply substituting 10 continuous digits with 10 number of X string and then printing the line.

Answer (score 0):

with `GNU sed`:

```
sed -r 's/\b[0-9]{10}\b/XXXXXXXXXX/g' filename
```